authorization error for mongo sync how to solve
I'm using Mongo Cluster to cluster sync, and when I try to run Mongosync
show error:
"error":"could not restore resume data from destination collection mongosync_reserved_for_internal_use.resumeData: error getting bootstrap data from resume data doc for mongosync with id 'coordinator' in destination collection mongosync_reserved_for_internal_use.resumeData: (Unauthorized) not authorized on mongosync_reserved_for_internal_use to execute command { find: \"resumeData\", filter: { _id: \"coordinator\" }, limit: 1, singleBatch: true, readConcern: { level: \"linearizable\" }, lsid: { id: UUID(\"**********\") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1712138125, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, **********), keyId: ********** } }, maxTimeMS: 300000, $db: \"mongosync_reserved_for_internal_use\", $readPreference: { mode: \"primary\" } }","message":"Mongosync errored while starting."}

How can I run Mongosync?
